# Windows 10 and IE 11 ActiveX not loaded

Tags: activex, internet-explorer-11, windows-10

We run IE11 on Windows 10 Technical Preview Build 10049

This javascript check returns false:

```
if ("ActiveXObject" in window) alert(‘ActiveX supported!’);
```

and this line

```
var objBonPrinter = new ActiveXObject('dispi.commport.Bonprinter');
```

returns the error "ActiveXObject is undefined"

So it seems the problem is not in the ActiveX component but on a higher level?
We have set all the security settings to allowed, just like we do in IE11 on Windows 8.1 which does run the same code fine.

edit: it works if we use IE11 in compatibilitymode. But it doesn't work without.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with IE11, the ActiveXObject property is hidden in favor of [cross-browser plugin detection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn423948(v=vs.85).aspx).

You'll need to update your code accordingly.

Hope this helps...

-- Lance

Answer (score -1):

I tested on the last Windows 10 Technical Preview Build 14372.

Unfortunately `ActiveXObject` doesn't work and there is no information in the logs.

And Yes, it works if we use IE11 in <=8 compatibility mode only.

As I know it, IE9 has different engine as compared to IE8 and I guess it is bug of IE Technical Preview.